# MongoDB TTL index doesn't delete expired documents

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, robo3t

I'm trying to create a collection named `ttl`, and using a TTL index, make the documents in that collection expire after 30 seconds.

I've created the collection using [`mongoengine`](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine), like so:

```
class Ttl(Document):
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {
                'name': 'TTL_index',
                'fields': ['expire_at'],
                'expireAfterSeconds': 0
            }
        ]
    }

    expire_at = DateTimeField()
```

The index has been created and Robo3T shows it's as expected.

The actual documents are inserted to the collection using `mongoengine` as well:

```
current_ttl = models.monkey.Ttl(expire_at=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30))
current_ttl.save()
```

The save is successful (the document is inserted into the DB), but it never expires!

How can I make the documents expire?

I'm adding the collection's contents here as well in case I'm saving them wrong. These are the results of running `db.getCollection('ttl').find({})`:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccf0f5a4bdc6edcd3773cd6"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-05-05T19:31:10.715Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccf121c0b792dae8f55cc80"),
    "expire_at" : ISODate("2019-05-05T19:41:08.220Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccf127d6729084a24772fad"),
    "expire_at" : ISODate("2019-05-05T19:42:47.522Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccf15bab124a97322da28de"),
    "expire_at" : ISODate("2019-05-05T19:56:56.359Z")
}
```

The indexes themselves, as per the results of `db.getCollection('ttl').getIndexes()`, are:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "monkeyisland.ttl"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "expire_at" : 1
        },
        "name" : "TTL_index",
        "ns" : "monkeyisland.ttl",
        "background" : false,
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 0
    }
]
```

My `db.version()` is 4.0.8 and it's running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Please post the output of `db.ttl.getIndexes()` from the `mongo` shell (not from Robo3T). I have a hunch that the TTL index was not setup like you expected.

Comment: Hi @KevinAdistambha 
I added the indexes of the collection to the question's body, any ideas?

Comment: Also added the DB version ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
current_ttl = models.monkey.Ttl(expire_at=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30))
```

that should be

```
current_ttl = models.monkey.Ttl(expire_at=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=30))
```